# Не записывает слова в префиксное дерево. Указатель child так и остается пустым. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить

Tags: c++

```
    struct Node {
    bool is_end_of_word;
    struct Node* child[26];
    string english;
}*head;

void init() {
    head = new Node();
    head->is_end_of_word = false;
}

void insert(string eng_word) {
    if (eng_word.empty())
        return;
    Node* current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < eng_word.size(); i++) {
        int indeks = int(eng_word[i]) - int('a');
        if (current->child[indeks] == nullptr) {
            current->child[indeks] = new Node();
        }
        current = current->child[indeks];
    }
    current->is_end_of_word = true;
    current->english = eng_word;
}



int main()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("myFile (1).txt");
    string word;
    if (file.is_open()) {
        while (!file.eof()) {
            getline(file, word);
            if (word[0] >= 97 && word[0] <= 122) {
                init();
                insert(word);
            }
        }
    }
    file.close();
    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) уже сотню раз было про этот несчастный `while (!file.eof())`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

2) у тебя глобальный параметр head который ты снова и снова инициализируешь в init() что ещё ты ожидаешь кроме утечки памяти и пустой головы тут?